# Prove or Disprove Invertible Matrix Identitiy

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Prove or disprove:

if $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(F)$ are invertible,
and also $A^{-1}B^{-1}AB=cI_n$, $c \in F$ then $c^n=1$.

I think it has to do with multiplying both sides by $A^{-1}B^{-1}$ but I don't know what I can do from there.

Comment: apply the determinant

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Take a determinant from both sides of the equation.

Remember: $\det(AB)=\det(A) \det(B)$, $\det(I)=1$ and $\det(cA)=c^n \det(A)$.

Comment: Can you explain why I’m allowed to take the determinant from both sides? Alternatively can you paste a link with an explanation? Thanks

Comment: @ikoikoia Well its allowed because if $A=B$ then $det(A)=det(B)$ ie the determinant is well defined function. You can check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057667/applying-a-function-to-both-sides-of-an-equation-doesnt-change-it